# SQL int to hex conversion little/big endian format

Tags: sql-server

Using MSSMS I'm trying to run the query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(16), 14437)
```

It results to:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000003865
```

But this is what I'm looking for:

```
0x65380000000000000000000000000000
```

I tried using reverse but no luck.

```
SELECT REVERSE(CONVERT(BINARY(16), 14437))
```

Comment: This not not "big" or "little" endian..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I tried using reverse but no luck.

`REVERSE` returns a string. Casting back to binary returns your desired results

```
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(16), REVERSE(CONVERT(BINARY(16), 14437)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can accept the answer after 11min. :)